# Looping on a JSON object to check if a given value exists

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Here is my JSON Object, i want to know in Angular 6 how can we search in key "name" if a value for example Tennis exist on it.

```
  {
  "id":2,
  "name":"Sports",
  "url":"/sports"
  "children":[
     {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Football"
     },
     {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Tennis"   
     },
     {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Soccer"
     }
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** to check whether value present,

```
var result = yurObj.children.some(t=>t.name === "Tennis");
```

DEMO

```js
var yourObj = {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Sports",
  "url": "/sports",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Football"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Tennis"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Soccer"
    }
  ]
};

var result = yourObj.children.some(t=>t.name === "Tennis");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: is that pratical if i use JSON.stringify() to my JSON object ?

Comment: you dont need to use, just check the demo

Comment: yourObj.children is not known result in my case is a list i only can map,filter,foreach .. methods to manage lists

Comment: i meant yourObj as the one you pasted above

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Array filter method:

```
const result = Object.children.filter(item => item.name === 'Tennis')
```

The result array will contain all elements of children where the name is equal to 'Tennis'.

Hope this helps.
Lloyd

Answer (score 0):

This is super easy using [lodash](https://lodash.com/). You can use `find` or `filter` methods. `find` will give you specific value whereas `filter` will return collection of values matching search criteria.

`const result = _.find(yourObj, {name: 'Tennis'});`

In case, you need to search within childern of your object, you can also do that so:

`const result = _.find(yourObj, function(o) { return o.children.name === 'Tennis' });`